# Why Fullscreen mode is working just in Samsung phone?

Tags: android, android-fullscreen, android-runtime

There are some questions about `Fullscreen` but in my case, I'm using one java class with `(AbsRuntimePermission extends AppCompatActivity)` and the `(MainActivity extends AbsRuntimePermission)`

My problem is: the `Fullscreen` mode is working just in the Samsung phone.

By the way, the Home button is my problem, the title is already hidden.

In my `MainActivity` I'm using this windows code:

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    requestAppPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            android.Manifest.permission.INTERNET, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, R.string.msg, REQUEST_PERMISSION);
```

In my Styles I'm using the `.AppCompat.NoActionBar`.

```
  <style name="PlayerTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
```

Following another questions about Fullscreen, I tryed to use this code in my styles

```
 <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
 <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
 <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
 <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
 <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
 </style>
```

and then change the manifest for theme `.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen` But it is not working.
 Are there any permission that I need to use when I have RuntimePermission?

Answer (score 0):

solved: i have check this code it works on android version 4.0.4  api(15) and some above versions

1. after content view **ADD this** `this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`

chnage your style into

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
```

2. if your using api level 19 or above than use `Immersive Full-Screen Mode` override this function it will works fine

ex:

```
     @Override
     public  void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean  hasFocus){
     super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
     View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    if(hasFocus){

    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                |View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY 
                |View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN  
                |View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION  
                |View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN  // hide status bar
                |View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    }
}
```

hope answered the question if its useful than vote up